# Is it ok (regarding spam) to use yahoo to send email from our domain me@mydomain.com?

Tags: email, email-server, spam, sendmail, spam-filter

I m enough of seeing my email arriving in spam folder. I would like now to send my emails not from my smtp server but from yahoo mail server. When you have a yahoo account, you can choose to send email from other sender (ie like me@mydomain.com). it's just a simple configuration we can do for free in all yahoo account (in some way I guess it's just changing the header of the email, putting me@mydomain.com in the sender instead of me@yahoo.com). Now is it safe regarding spam to send emails like this? what are the pro and cons?

Comment: Why would your mail end up as spam when actually using your own specific smtp server??

Answer (score 0):

Regarding sending an email using aliases is not a good idea because mostlikely your email will get blocked unless it's permitted by the domain policy such as:

- SPF Records opened to that particular Sender
- DKIM policy

I strongly suggest you to use a proper authenticated email and do not use aliases because overriding the email headers might trigger some antispam filters thus blackholing your emails